# How do I open files in a new tab from :Lexplore in VIM

Tags: vim

When using `netrw` as `:Lex`, opening a file simply replaces the current file open. How do I open a file in a new tab from Lex or in a new vertical split?

Comment: What is a Lex? Why is this tagged Vim?

Comment: `:Lexplore` or `:Lex` in shortcut, opens `netrw` on the left side of vim.

Comment: If they were going to migrate this, they might as well have migrated to [vi.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`:h netrw-t`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html?#netrw-t):

```
BROWSING WITH A NEW TAB                         netrw-t

Normally one enters a file or directory using the <cr>.  The "t" map
allows one to open a new window holding the new directory listing or file in
a new tab.

If you'd like to have the new listing in a background tab, use gT.
```

And `:h netrw-v`:

```
BROWSING WITH A VERTICALLY SPLIT WINDOW                 netrw-v

Normally one enters a file or directory using the <cr>.  However, the "v" map
allows one to open a new window to hold the new directory listing or file.  A
vertical split is used.  (for horizontal splitting, see netrw-o)

Normally, the v key splits the window vertically with the new window and
cursor at the left.
```

Just press `t` instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> for a new tab, or `v` for a new vertical split.

Comment: Thanks. While opening file in a new tab with `t`, it opens the file in a new unsplit window. Can I modify it to act like other IDEs, i.e. open the file tabed in the existing right split window? I couldn't find this in `:h netrw-t`

Comment: In Vim, tabs contain splits. Splits can't contain tabs.